# Returning Address of Local Variable Generates Unexpected Value

Tags: pointers, go, stack

I have written the below code. I know that returning the address of a variable which was
created in a function is a wrong approach since the created local variable will be in stack, and 
after completing the function the variable will be popped from stack. 
I have created a person whose name is 'latif'. Then I have used changeName() function. It changes name field of the person struct as 'uluman'. It has returned the address of the local variable.  After finishing the function, the local variable should be popped. Then I have called sum() function for guarenting that the stack will change (paremeters of sum function will pushed. With other words, the cell value x points in the memory should change ). So the x points somewhere in stack.

```
package main
    import "fmt"

    type Person struct{
        name string
        age int

    }
    func sum(a, b int)int{
       return a+b
    }
    func (t Person ) changeName(value string)*Person{
        t.name = value
        return &t  //Delibiratly the address of the local variable is returned
    }
    func main(){
        t := Person{name : "latif" }

        fmt.Println("Before" , t.name)
        x := t.changeName("uluman")
        _= sum(5,10)
        fmt.Println("After" , x.name)



        return
    }
```

I have expected that the **fmt.Println(x.name)** should print something different from **'uluman'** since the x points stack address and it has changed, but it has printed 'uluman'.
What is wrong in here?

Comment: x does not point to a stack address. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38234487/returning-a-pointer-on-stack, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52996452/returning-pointer-from-a-local-variable-in-function, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52996452/returning-pointer-from-a-local-variable-in-function, etc

Comment: "the address of a variable which was created in a function is a wrong approach since the created local variable will be in stack, and after completing the function the variable will be popped from stack" false. Any variable that will have a pointer taken of it will be allocated on the heap and managed by GC.

Comment: @JimB thanks for your response. I could not find the links.

Comment: The [specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec) is silent on the distinction between heap and stack allocation. In fact, spec does not contain the words "heap" or "stack".  The question is based on conceptual baggage from some other language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called "escape analysis".

Go compiler tries to find out if the address of a variable "escapes" a function, and if it does, it allocates the variable in the heap instead of stack. In this case, it finds that the address of `t` escapes the `changeName` function, so it is allocated in the heap, not in the stack. That is the reason why your program works.

For instance, this is a common way to construct structs:

```
type X struct {
  ...
}

func NewX() *X {
   a:=X{}
   ...
   return &a
}
```

Here, `a` is allocated in the heap, not on stack because the compiler knows that `a` escapes the function.

The following is also valid:

```
func f() {
  i:=0
  go func() {
    ...
    i++
    ...
   }()
}
```

Above, `i` escapes `f`, because address of `i` is in the closure of the newly created goroutine. After `f` returns, `i` continues to live.